# How to check if the system has enough resources for another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing a c++ function for merge sort using multithreading with the `#include <thread>` library and i don't know how to limit the number of threads such that the programs doesn't crash.

I tried putting the declaration of a the new thread in a try block but then i have run out of scope. The following is the code of the MergeSort function

```
vector < int > V;

// st == left margin of interval
// dr == right margin of interval 
void MergeSort( int st, int dr ) {

    static int limit = 0;

    int mid = ( st + dr ) / 2;

    if ( st >= dr ) {
        return ;
    }

    if ( limit > 200 ) {   // i tried to manually limit the number of threads 
        MergeSort( st, mid );
        MergeSort( mid + 1, dr );
        Merge( st, dr );                  // this merge the 2 sub arrays 
        return ;
    }

    thread t1 { MergeSort, st, mid };
    thread t2 { MergeSort, mid + 1, dr };

    limit += 2;

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    limit -= 2;

    Merge( st, dr );

}
```

Comment: ***i don't know how to limit the number of threads such that the programs doesn't crash.*** you should probably limit the threads to the number of physical processor cores (or even a few more for logical cores which provide ballpark 0% to 30% extra performance in the x86 platform) not by how much memory is required to create the stack for each thread.

Comment: You will have to use  some OS functionality to determine how much memory you can allocate in your process. Standard `c++` itself has none of this. The solution would be different from linux/android to other operating systems.

Comment: Unrelated, but `static int limit = 0;` will make your MergeSort only good for doing one threaded sorting during the program run.

Comment: It would probably be better to set a lower limit on the size of a chunk that each thread handles before worrying about the number of threads.   While the number of threads generally shouldn't exceed the number of cores, small chunks means that the overhead of launching the thread exceeds the benefit of using threads at all.

Comment: @Peter setting a limit on the size of the chunk made a very big difference, thank you. I`m testing the program on  a 1 mil. array and i had an reduction in execution time of 75%. This suggestions kills 2 birds with one stone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that due to the following two bugs, your program is spawning far more than 200 threads.

First, your program is undefined behavior, since you are changing *limit* from different threads at the same time without any synchronization mechanism, which is illegal. The easiest way to avoid this is to use `atomic`:

```cpp
static std::atomic<int> limit = 0;
```

Second, you should do the limit updating *before* you spawn the new threads. Otherwise, the new threads might themselves spawn new threads, and so on, and so on, before you ever run `limit += 2` in any of them. In general the order in which different threads run in C++ is not guaranteed.